# how can i add a reference to a .dll in my bin without having visual studio access

Tags: .net, dll, reference

I need to add a reference to a dll on a website i dont have visual studio access to. i only have ftp access. just wondering what files change when the reference is made? is it something i could upload do through ftp?

thanks for any help.

phil

Comment: What do you intend to do with this reference? If no code changes, why add it?

Comment: im adding a captcha to a form http://www.captcha.net/ so i need to add a reference to the recatcha.dll they give me. i have the site locally so i have checked the code and everythings fine. i just need to upload the individual files i have changed.

Comment: Why can't you upload the whole site?

Comment: @phili: I think you can upload the DLL into the bin folder and upload the referenced Page / Usercontrol, it will work automatically; unless there is any change in your project assemblies.

Comment: Please watch the language, people.

Answer (score 0):

If its a website project you don't have to add a reference, just add the .dll to the bin directory and it should work.